# Powershell try/catch validate all test, if one of the test validation failed, it then exits the loop and shows the error?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-7.0

How to modify the code below so if one of the test validation failed, it then exits the loop and shows the error?

```
#Test the DNS server functionality, if no errors, generated from the below test, then all is good, exit script.
        try
        {
            $testConnection = Test-Connection $domaincontroller -Count 1
            If (($testConnection -ne "") -or ($testconnection -ne $null))
            {
                Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4
                Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -Context Forwarder
                Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -Context RootHints
                Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -ZoneName $env:USERDOMAIN
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "$computername DNS test failed".
                Exit
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Output "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
            Write-Output "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
```

Comment: what loop? please remember to provide minimal code that shows your Question or Problem. [*grin*]

Comment: Add "-ErrorAction Stop" argument after Test-Connection and Test-DnsServer cmd-let calls so that a terminal exception is caught within the try block to go to Catch{}. You then also do not need If (($testConnection -ne "") -or ($testconnection -ne $null)) line as the execution wil not get that far, it will go to your Catch{} block.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it is just the section of the DNS functionality testing where I need  to trigger the error when just one single test is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your commands. It will "Catch" as soon as one of them fails - anything below that point will not be processed. As noted above your If...Then statement is largely redundant:

```
Try {
    $testConnection = Test-Connection $domaincontroller -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
    Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -ErrorAction Stop
    Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -Context Forwarder -ErrorAction Stop
    Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -Context RootHints -ErrorAction Stop
    Test-DnsServer -IPAddress $ipV4 -ZoneName $env:USERDOMAIN -ErrorAction Stop
{
Catch {
    Write-Output $testConnection
    Write-Output "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
    Write-Output "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

Comment: does the -EA Stop means, if there is an error then stop the script and execute the catch section?

Comment: Bascially, yes.